# checking if URL request is already in NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsoperationqueue

I have a `NSOperationQueue` that takes in a bunch of operation download request. The question is how do I check if I have a specific URL already on the `NSOperationQueue`? Because if it's alreayd in the queue I don't want to enqueue it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass `NSOperation` (if you haven't done so already), add a `URL` property to your subclass, and check whether an operation with the URL you're about to add is already in  the queue:

```
if (![[queue.operations valueForKey:@"URL"] containsObject:myURL]) {
   //add operation...
} else {
   //operation with this URL is already in the queue...
}
```

If you have *lots* of operations going on, you might want to track the URLs separately in an `NSMutableSet` which is more efficient for membership testing. You'd then have to remove the URL from the set when an operation completes.